# Adjusting JSON URL to match required API URL

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm trying to connect to already existing API's in Python. Problem is different URL's

the URL should be:

```
/engineering/sappr1-qa/dirdetails/fetchdetails?Application=CTV&DocumentName=G76410&FileID=FOL43000000015861EXT47000000001577
```

Instead I get:

```
/engineering/sappr1-qa/dirdetails/fetchdetails?%24filter=Application%20eq%20%27CTV%27%20and%20DocumentName%20eq%20%27G76410%27%20and%20FileID%20eq%20%27FOL43000000015861EXT47000000001577%27&%24format=json
```

I wrote it with the following script which worked for the other API's:

```
@app.get("/dirdetails/fetchdetails")

async def custom_operation5(
    
    Application: str = Query("CTV", description="Application"),
    DocumentName: str = Query("G76410", description="DocumentName"),
    FileID: str = Query("FOL43000000015861EXT47000000001577", description="FileID"),
    format: str = Query("json", description="Response format")
    
):
    path="/dirdetails/fetchdetails" ## Path to be modified as per get call ###

    url = f"{settings.api_baseurl}{settings.api_env}{path}"
   
    ## For any column changes needs to make changes to the filter query ##

    filter_query = f"Application eq '{Application}' and DocumentName eq '{DocumentName}' and FileID eq '{FileID}'"

    params = {
        "$filter": filter_query,
        "$format": format
    }

    try:
        url_with_params = f"{url}?{urlencode(params)}"
        async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
            response = await client.get(url, params=params, auth=auth, headers=common_headers)
            response.raise_for_status()
            return response.json()
    
    except httpx.HTTPError as e:
        return {"error": str(e)}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"error": "An unexpected error occurred."}
```

I know I should remove the filter. However, I need to know how I should built up the script instead of just removing it in the above script, which doesn't work. Some background theory in the way the URL's work would welcome as well.

I need to know how I should built up the script.  Instead of just removing the filter and JSON in the above script, which doesn't work. Some background theory in the way the URL's work would welcome as well.

Comment: I think `urlencode(params)` should be `urlencode(params['$filter'])` to get what you want.

Comment: How do you expect `Application eq '{Application}'` to be turned into `Application=CTV` automatically?

Comment: @Barmar it fixed the extension but now I get the error:  "error": "An unexpected error occurred."
}

Comment: Why don't you return the actual exception instead of hiding it as "unexpected error"